# Deploy WCF web service on IIS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, web-services, deployment

I developed a WCF service which works fine at the machine for development. Now i want to deploy it on another server without VisualStudio, only with IIS and .Net framework installed.
I want to confirm whether the following steps are correct or not:

1. Pick WCF Files: web.config; Service.svc; and Bin foloder (Service.dll)
2. Put WCF files in one IIS directory, and link to a vitual dir
3. Browse it

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that should be sufficient.

The simplest means of deploying (assuming permissions and network connectivity) is to right-click the project in Visual Studio and select publish.  You can publish to a folder that you've already set up as a virtual directory.